# Insert data to a new column, while depending on data from another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, insert, multiple-columns

I have added a new column to my table:

```
Column Name: "Status"
DataType = varchar
```

In the same table I have an existed column called `Bin` with datatype `INT`, and it contains the values: 0 and 1 (1000 rows).

What I want to do, is to insert the word "Success" to "Status" whenever "Bin"=1, and "Failure" when "Bin"=0.

Any ideas how to perform this using SQL statement?

Comment: Seems you want an **`UPDATE`** and a `CASE` expression. An `INSERT` *inserts* a new row, `UPDATE` *updates* an existing row. (Side note, if `Bin` can only contain the values `0` and `1`, why is it an `int` and not a `bit`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Case` expression you can update your table.

```
Update table_name
 Set Status = Case Bin 
                 WHEN 1 THEN 'Success'
                 WHEN 0 THEN 'Failure'
               END
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding a column to store completely deterministic data you could add a *computed column* for this purpose:

```
alter table T add [Status] as case Bin when 1 then 'Success' else 'Failure' end
```